# box - cannot create new collaboration using the nodeJS box sdk

Tags: node.js, box

I am building an app that uses box, and I want to add a collaboration on my folder for a given user.

Looking at [box doc](https://github.com/box/box-node-sdk/blob/master/docs/collaborations.md) I am doing the following :

```
const assignUserToFolder = function(appUserId) {

    //Get App auth client
    const boxAdminClient = 
        BoxSdk.getAppAuthClient('enterprise', process.env.BOX_ENTERPRISE_ID);
    console.log(`assign user ${appUserId} to folder ${process.env.BOX_FOLDER_ID}`);
    boxAdminClient.collaborations.createWithUserID(
      appUserId, 
      process.env.BOX_FOLDER_ID, 
      boxAdminClient.collaborationRoles.EDITOR, (
        function (error, boxResponse) {
          if (error) {
            console.log(`error ${error}`);
          }
    }));

};
```

I have verified that the box client is correct and appUserId and the folderId have correct values.

I have also tested directly using the [API](https://developer.box.com/reference#add-a-collaboration) directly and I was able to update and set the correct role for my folder.

but even when I put the equivalent to my node code

```
const assignUserToFolderAPI = function(appUserId) {
    var requestParams = {
      body: {
        item: {
          id: process.env.BOX_FOLDER_ID,
          type: "folder"
        },
        accessible_by: {
          id: appUserId,
          type: "user"
        },
        role: "editor"
      }
    };

    //Get App auth client
    const boxAdminClient = BoxSdk.getAppAuthClient('enterprise', process.env.BOX_ENTERPRISE_ID);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        //Create the collaboration in Box
        console.log(`create collaboration for user ${appUserId}`);
        boxAdminClient.post('/collaborations', requestParams, boxAdminClient.defaultResponseHandler(function(error, boxResponse) {
                if (error) {
                reject(error);
                console.log(requestParams);
                  }

                  resolve(boxResponse);
          }));
    });
};
```

I get the following error messsage

```
"errorMessage": "Unexpected API Response [404 Not Found] (not_found: \"Not Found\")",
```

When I review the requestParams, both `item.id` and `accessible_by.id` are correct, and it works just fine from CLI.

Does anyone know why this would not work ? could it be an issue with the service account I am using ?

In the box app:

- Application Access is Enterprise
- I've selected all Application Scopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it ended up having nothing to do with the version.
This should work...

```
adminAPIClient.enterprise.getUsers({filter_term: FOLDER_OWNER_EMAIL}, function (err, users) {
 var owner = users.entries[0];
 var userAPIClient = sdk.getAppAuthClient('user', owner.id);  // folder owner id

userAPIClient.collaborations.createWithUserID(
APP_USER_ID,   
FOLDER_ID, 
userAPIClient.collaborationRoles.EDITOR, 
function(err, data) {
  console.log(err);
   });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot kendomen, I understand why it would work but I am still struggling on my side to make it work. I get directly `var appUserClient = BoxSdk.getAppAuthClient('user', '2442376096');` where it is the id of the user owning the folder. I verified that appUserClient is correct, but still it does not seem to fire when I am calling `userAPIClient.collaborations.createWithUserID` method

Comment: It probably needs to be as-user enabled and then reauthorized

Comment: What do you mean reauthorized ? I am not sure I'm following

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to run fine when I ran it passing an appUserId and a valid folderId.  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I run it in an was lambda and I can see log in cloud watch `assign user xxx to folder xxx` where both values are valid. I dont have any error log neither.

Comment: which version of the box sdk are you running ? I run latest version 1.9.0

Answer (score 0):

try running this to see the collaborations on that folder:

```
boxAdminClient.folders.getCollaborations('xxxxxx', null, function(err, data) {
      console.log(data);
      data.entries.forEach(function(element) {
          console.log(element)
      }, this);
  })
```

Comment: I get `undefined` - are you using the same `BoxSdk.getAppAuthClient` ? from the box app I've assigned all Application Scopes

Comment: Yes.  Ok, can you try hard-coding your enterprise_id but put it between ' '

Comment: I believe my enterprise_id and the boxAdminClient are working fine, I'm able to create app users from my app but I cannot assign the right access level on a given existing folder

Comment: Do you have your app As-User enabled?

Comment: no - I've added `boxAdminClient.asUser(appUserId);` to my code before calling the method but no better result

Comment: You're right.  after i updated to box-node-sdk 1.9.0, it fails.  Let me see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks - will downgrade for now, can you tell me which version you've used ? is 1.8.0 good enough or 1.7.0